# How to query in top level array in couchbase?

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase collection where I am storing each record as an array as below

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1237,
    "customerId": 1561
  },
  {
    "id": 1238,
    "customerId": 1562    
  }
]
```

Now I want to query this array where customerId = xyz;

How do I achieve this using N1 query?

Answer (score 0):

The document it self is scalar ARRAY vs OBJECT it is hard to create index and might need primary index.

```
INSERT INTO default VALUES("f01", [ { "id": 1237, "customerId": 1561 }, { "id": 1238, "customerId": 1562
} ]);

SELECT u.*
FROM default AS d
UNNEST d AS u
WHERE u.customerId = 1561;
```